# Почему не выполняется ALTER TABLE UPDATE clickhouse

Tags: php, sql, laravel, clickhouse

Пишу api на laravel.
**Использую:**

1. clickhouse 23.7.3.
2. php 8.0
3. glushkovds/phpclickhouse-laravel
4. apache2

Столкнулся с проблемой, что данные в таблице не изменяются. Причем, что удивительно, точно такой же запрос на эту же таблицу работает.

Итак, задача запроса:
Удалять из массива users пользователя, который хочет "выйти из комнаты". А так же, удалять все устройства из массива devices, которые принадлежат пользователю.

Код не работающего запроса:

```
<?php
 
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
 
function exitFromRoom($roomId, Request $request){
$userId = $request->user_id;
 
try {
DB::statement("ALTER TABLE Rooms UPDATE users = arrayFilter(x -> x != $userId, users),
     devices = arrayFilter(x -> !arrayExists(x -> x.owner_id =  $userId, users), devices)
     WHERE arrayExists(x -> x = $userId, users) AND room_id = $roomId");
print("Hello");
 
return ['result' => true, 'data'=> "Successfully exit!", 'code'=> config('httpConstants.OK')];
}
catch(Exception $ex){
createSystemEvent(config('eventTypes.SentAnswer'), config('eventDescriptions.SendBadAnswer'), $userId, NULL, $request->ip(),
['result' => false, 'data' => $ex->getMessage(), 'code' => config('httpConstants.Unknown_Error')]);
 
return ['result' => false, 'data'=> $ex->getMessage(), 'code'=> config('httpConstants.Unknown_Error')];
}
}
```

в ходе тестов заметил, что print даже не выполняется. Как будто код зависает на этом моменте и не продолжает работу. Или выбивает ошибку, которую не выводит.

Код работающего кода:

```
Devices::where('device_id', (int) $macCode)->update(['owner_id' => 0]);
 
DB::statement("ALTER TABLE Rooms UPDATE devices = arrayFilter(x -> x != $macCode, devices) WHERE arrayExists(x -> x = $owner_id,users) AND room_id = $roomId");
```

Comment: @Akina
1) Документация: https://clickhouse.com/docs/ru/sql-reference/statements/alter/update
2.1) Если использовать DELETE, то будет удаляться полностью запись. А мне нужно удалять именно из массива **idшники** пользователя и устройства. Поэтому я использую update. 
2.2) В **clickhouse** есть массивы: https://clickhouse.com/docs/ru/sql-reference/functions/array-functions

Comment: Ох ёёё... да, это совсем не SQL... сорри.

Comment: @Akina
Ну... SQL, но не чистый. Ничего страшного, спасибо за попытку.

Comment: Раз у вас возникает необходимость удаления или обновления существующих записей, то есть подозрение что вы выбрали не ту БД, т.к. КХ аналитическая бд которая предназначена для складывания данных для последующего анализа

Comment: @Nikolay вы правы, однако начальство решило так. На мои возражения и аргументы мне сказали "хотим скорости. Иди делай".

Comment: @FroggerProgger я видел ровно такуюже ситуацию на предыдущем месте работы. Подходящее решение никто внедрять не берётся (сложно, долго и можно облажаться). Поэтому решили делать реализацию через  ReplacingMergeTree. Важно помнить работая с КХ то что при выборе вам может прийти сразу нескольуо записей с одинаковым первичным ключём т.к. в эту БД планировали только добавлятб записи, причем для некоторых движков удаление записи производится через вставку новой записи )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете форкнуть мой адаптер и подключить его к Laravel, т.к. он канонично написан под Symfony, однако, там реализована возможность использования SyncResponse, т.к. ALTER TABLE в Clickouse у вас отрабатывает, но вы не видите мгновенного результата из-за мутаций (это ассинхронная операция, ClickHouse отвечает, что операция выполнена, однако, при следующем запросе вы получите предыдущий dataset, т.к. backgroud процесс of mutation еще не завершился).

PHPClickHouseAdapter: https://github.com/Borislavv/php-clickhouse-adapter

Answer (score -1):

В итоге. Спустя несколько недель проблема решилась.
Как таковое решение найти я не смог.
Просто заново щелкнул проект и переустановил ClickHouse пару тройку раз.

Comment: Не стоит добавлять в качестве ответа фразу "ответа я так и не нашел"